# Very Huge Integers

Tags: integer, biginteger

What programming language would allow me to print or multiply huge integers? When i say huge I mean 2<sup>5,000,000</sup>. I usually use java but I'm pretty sure that the biggest number(int or not) that i can achieve is by using doubles. 1.8*10<sup>308</sup> which still isn't enough. The answer doesn't have to be java specific.

Furthermore I tried to be silly and tried:

```
    double max1 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double max2 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(max1 * max2);
```

I got infinity...

Comment: You're looking for BigInteger.

Comment: thank you so much its flawless. But do you any compiler that can print 2^50. Eclipse crashed and died.

Comment: Eclipse probably ran out of memory.  Try writing it to a file.

Comment: @Ibrahim: assuming you mean 2^5000000, not 2^50, then BigInteger is the right type (2^50 could be done by a 64 bit long, in Java). If the IDE crashes, then something is wrong. 2^5000000 has approx 2 million digits. Should be no problem at all, although it may take a long while to calculate the string (perhaps the IDE didn't crash at all, it just waited for the result, which can take many minutes).

Comment: @SLaks: Out of memory? Hardly. 2^5000000 only need 625000 bytes, or approx 625 kilobytes. The printout would require 2 million digits, i.e. approx 4MB. Should not make any serious language run out of memory.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, but the textbox in the debugger could easily crash.

Comment: @SLaks: no problems in NetBeans.

Comment: Many languages support arbitrary precision integers. Python has excellent support, with native code for the underlying arithmetic.